# Bootstrap modal toggle() and modal('show') behaving differently

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7 and I have a modal dialog that contains a form. For validating the form I use jquery validation 1.16.0.

I show the modal with:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

I register a function for the submit button's click that checks if the validation succeeds with:

```
$('#myForm').valid()
```

and if so, makes an ajax call.
The submit button is enabled like this:

```
<button type="submit" id="btnDo" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Do</button>
```

The issue is that the modal is dismissed even if the validation of the form fails. If the modal is shown again, the validation error messages are there, so the validation itself performs properly, it's just the dialog that gets dismissed.

I managed to solve this issue by showing the modal with:

```
$('#myModal').toggle();
```

instead of modal('show').
However, a new annoyance appeared, the modal is not scroll-able anymore, which I had to solve by setting style="overflow-y: scroll;" on the modal div.

So, my 2 questions are:

1. What's the difference between showing a modal with toggle() vs
   modal('show'), that stopped the modal from being dismissed when the
   form validation failed?
2. Why using toggle() makes the modal
   non-scroll-able?

Thanks.

**Updated**

As requested, I included some relevant code.

The relevant HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show modal" />

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="myForm" class="well form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName">Name</label>
                    <div>
                        <input class="form-control"
                               required 
                               type="text"
                               id="inputName"
                               name="inputName"
                               data-val="true"
                               data-val-required="The name is required." />
                        <div class="text-danger" data-valmsg-for="inputName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" id="btnDo" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Do</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script:

```
$('#btnShow').click(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});

$('#btnDo').click(function() {
  console.log('Is my form valid? - ' + $('#myForm').valid());
});
```

Comment: Also, there's not nearly enough code shown here to reproduce a demo.

Comment: @Sparky It was a typo, it's '#myForm', the validation was working. I included some relevant code. Thanks.

Comment: FYI - `.toggle()` is simply a jQuery method that toggles the visibility of a hidden element... it has nothing specific to do with modals.

Comment: ... hence my bewilderment. :) But then I guess the .modal('show') does more than just showing the modal...

Comment: The modal is not scrollable because I'm guessing it's constructed when the page loads or when it's initially called.  Then when you call validation, the contents overflow and it does not expand to compensate.  You'll have to study the docs for `.modal()` and see if there's a method you can call to force it to re-render itself when content dynamically changes.

Comment: What's so bewildering?  You have a hidden element... using `toggle()` simply shows it.  Using `.modal()` turns it into a modal... two totally different things.

Comment: Because I thought modal('show') is pretty much the same thing. however, then maybe I should've asked why calling modal() dismisses the dialog when the form is invalid...

Comment: By default, the modal's button is probably set to always dismiss it upon `click` without any regard to your desire to keep it open when validation fails.  Again, refer to the options for the `.modal()` method to keep it open even when you interact with the button.  Then inside the `.validate()` method, you can dismiss it programmatically within the `submitHandler`.

Comment: I'm looking at the docs... you are telling it to close!  See:  `data-dismiss="modal"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the difference between showing a modal with `toggle()` vs `modal('show')`, ...

jQuery `.toggle()` simply shows and hides an element.  Bootstrap's `.modal()` constructs a modal... not the same thing as simply toggling visibility.

> ... that stopped the modal from being dismissed when the form validation failed?

By using the `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute within your button you are telling the `.modal()` method to dismiss the modal when the button is clicked.  It does not care that you have an invalid form inside.

Remove `data-dismiss="modal"` from your button and programmatically close the modal only when the form is valid.

```
submitHandler: function(form) { // only fires on valid form
    // handle your form submission:
    // $(form).submit(); // regular submission
    // OR
    // your Ajax         // Ajax submission

    // then close the modal
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
```

> Why using `toggle()` makes the modal non-scroll-able?

Because the size of the element is calculated when the page is constructed.  The `.toggle()` method uses the initial size and does not take into account any dynamic changes when the element is re-hidden.

If you want a modal, you should use `.modal()` as designed, otherwise with `.toggle()` you're not implementing a modal at all.

Comment: Source for this info?